# Unable to call Web API controller method with ajax in Asp .Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Unable to call Web API controller method using ajax jquery in Asp.Net.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/UnitsAPI/GetZones',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { "knownCategoryValues": 1, "category": Zone },
        success: function (response) {
            // $('#lblData').html(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

My controller

```
[HttpGet] 
public IHttpActionResult GetZones(string knownCategoryValues, string category) 
{ 
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(); 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    string strConn = GetConnectionInfo(); 
    sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn); 
    sqlConn.Open(); int stateID = 1; 
    NonCellUnit unit = new NonCellUnit();
    List<Unit> unitList = new List<Unit>(); 
    unitList = unit.GetChildUnits(stateID, true); return Ok(unitList); 
}
```

Comment: Add your WebApi method

Comment: What happens when you open that url in a browser?  We need more information about what actually happens in order to help.

Comment: @Div Because of the use of the word controller, I'm assuming it's MVC so the URL would be the controller and action.

Comment: When I open it in URL it's triggering method in Web APi but if I run by application side it's not triggering. But this Ajax I am calling from .ASPX form.

Comment: @Archer, Yes, you're right, here we also have to see that how OP define parameters at controller side.

Comment: @bujjibabu, *it's not triggering.* are you getting any console error?

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetZones(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            string strConn = GetConnectionInfo();
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

            sqlConn.Open();
            int stateID = 1;
            NonCellUnit unit = new NonCellUnit();
            List<Unit> unitList = new List<Unit>();
            unitList = unit.GetChildUnits(stateID, true);

            return Ok(unitList);
        }

Comment: No console error @Div.

Comment: add attribute routing `[Route("UnitsAPI/GetZones")]` thius might help

Comment: Your action should get two string values but as I see you are sending int to knownCategoryValues and some unknown Zone to  category.

Try to sent not 1 but  "1"  and make sure that Zone is also string value

Comment: What is your controller name?@bujjibabu

Comment: @Saurabh my controller name is UnitsAPIController.

Comment: Try this Url : `../UnitsAPI/GetZones` in your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute routing begening of your controller

```
[Route("api/UnitsAPI/GetZones")]
```

and request as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/UnitsAPI/GetZones',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { "knownCategoryValues": 1, "category": Zone },
        success: function (response) {
            // $('#lblData').html(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using WebApi, so you have default `api` in your route

So, you can try like `url: 'api/UnitsAPI/GetZones'` in your ajax call and change data like

```
data: { "knownCategoryValues": "1", "category": Zone }
```